# mysql unique combination of two columns

Tags: mysql

This is friends table

```
userid(int) | friendid(int) | confirmed(tiny int)
--------------------
1 | 2 | 1
2 | 1 | 1
1 | 3 | 1
3 | 1 | 1
1 | 5 | 0
2 | 4 | 1
4 | 2 | 1
4 | 1 | 1
1 | 4 | 1
```

I have about 200k rows like this
I want to delete duplicates example if userid=1 and friendid=2 then I dont want next row userid=2 friendid=1

I want unique combination across 2 columns means if 1,2 is there then 2,1 should not be there and should be deleted.

Then I can make friend list query like this:

```
select * from friends where (userid=1 or friendid=1) and confirmed=1
```

My questions:

How to delete this duplicate rows?

Please also give me query to find mutual friends of 2 user( userid of them may reside in either userid column or friendid in friends table).

Comment: Don't ask two questions in the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table with itself to find the rows with the same pair of users in the opposite order.

```
DELETE f1 
FROM friends as f1
JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.userid = f2.friendid AND f1.friendid = f2.userid
WHERE f1.friendid > f1.userid
```

The `WHERE` clause ensure that we only delete one of the two rows in the set.